# How do I fixed Shader Error in WebGl on safari

Tags: reactjs, three.js, next.js

I try to create Three.js in next.js following this tutorial.

https://codesandbox.io/s/1mbwc?file=/src/Gl.js

it work fine in safari but in chrome there are an errors.
I have no idea to fixed it. even thought I try to searching this bug.

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders  THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment
ERROR: 0:15: 'fwidth' : no matching overloaded function found
1: #ifdef GL_OES_standard_derivatives
2: #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
3: #endif
4: precision highp float;
5: uniform float opacity;
6: uniform vec3 color;
7: uniform sampler2D map;
8: varying vec2 vUv;
9: float median(float r, float g, float b) {
10:   return max(min(r, g), min(max(r, g), b));
11: }
12: void main() {
13:   vec3 sample = texture2D(map, vUv).rgb;
14:   float sigDist = median(sample.r, sample.g, sample.b) - 0.5;
15:   float alpha = clamp(sigDist/fwidth(sigDist) + 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
16:   gl_FragColor = vec4(color.xyz, alpha * opacity);
17:   if (gl_FragColor.a < 0.0001) discard;
18: }
```

And This is my code.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import shaders from './shaders'

const loadFont = require('load-bmfont')
const createGeometry = require('three-bmfont-text')
const OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE)

const MSDFShader = require('three-bmfont-text/shaders/msdf')
const fontFile = require('./assets/Orbitron-Black.fnt')
const fontAtlas = require('./assets/Orbitron-Black.png')

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth
  / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000)
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
const clock = new THREE.Clock()

let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 })
let loader
let fontGeometry
let fontMaterial
let rt
let rtScene
let rtCamera
let cube

camera.position.z = 3
function render() {
  controls.update()
  cube.rotation.y += 0.005

  material.uniforms.uTime.value = clock.getElapsedTime()

  renderer.setRenderTarget(rt)
  renderer.render(rtScene, rtCamera)

  renderer.setRenderTarget(null)
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  render()
}

function createRenderTarget() {
  rt = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(
    window.innerWidth,
    window.innerHeight,
  )
  rtScene = new THREE.Scene()
  rtScene.background = new THREE.Color('#000000')

  rtCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 0.1, 1000)
  rtCamera.position.z = 2.5

  const text = new THREE.Mesh(fontGeometry, fontMaterial)
  text.position.set(-0.965, -0.275, 0)
  text.rotation.set(Math.PI, 0, 0)
  text.scale.set(0.008, 0.02, 1)

  rtScene.add(text)
}

function createMesh() {
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)

  material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: shaders.vert,
    fragmentShader: shaders.frag,
    uniforms: {
      uTime: { value: 0 },
      uTexture: { value: rt.texture },
    },
  })

  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
  scene.add(cube)
}

function resize() {
  const width = window.innerWidth
  const height = window.innerHeight

  this.camera.aspect = width / height
  this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
  this.renderer.setSize(width, height)
}

function addEvents() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => resize)
}

function init() {
  loadFont(fontFile.default, (err, font) => {
    fontGeometry = createGeometry({
      font,
      text: 'FOXBITH',
    })
  })

  loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
  loader.load(fontAtlas, (texture) => {
    fontMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial(
      MSDFShader({
        map: texture,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        transparent: true,
        negate: false,
        color: 0xffffff,
      }),
    )
    createRenderTarget()
    createMesh()
    animate()
    addEvents()
  })
}

init()
function MagicBox() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const mount = document.getElementById('mount')
    mount.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

    renderer.setSize((window.innerWidth / 2), (window.innerHeight / 2))
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 1.5))
    renderer.setClearColor(0x00000, 1)
    return () => {
      window.addEventListener('resize', () => resize)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <Box background="pink" position="absolute" right="0">
      <div id="mount" />
    </Box>
  )
}

export default MagicBox
```

thanks for help
thanks for helpthanks for helpthanks for helpthanks for helpthanks for help

Comment: This is saying that the browser is unable to enable the `GL_OES_standard_derivatives` extension and without it, your `fwidth()` function doesn't exist. [Check here for browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OES_standard_derivatives), I'm pretty sure both Chrome and Safari support it. Maybe you'll need to force a WebGL1 context with `WebGL1Renderer` instead of `WebGLRenderer`? I'm not entirely sure...

Comment: omg! that 's fixed my ploblem.

Comment: Huh, glad to hear it! It was a shot in the dark, so I'm glad it worked out!